# Users.labels: delete Javascript example code raises a 'Missing name after . operator.' error in script.google.com

Tags: gmail-api

I copied and pasted on [script.google.com](http://script.google.com) the example code from [delete labels documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/delete):

```
/**
 * Delete Label with given ID.
 *
 * @param  {String} userId User's email address. The special value 'me'
 * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
 * @param  {String} labelId ID of Label to delete.
 */
function deleteLabel(userId, labelId) {
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.delete({ // <- error line
    'userId': userId,
    'id': labelId
  });
  request.execute(function(resp) { });
}
```

When I try and save the script, this error appears:
`Missing name after . operator. (line 9, file "deleteLabel")`

It seems like the problem is the word 'delete', as the error disappears when I substitute it with any other word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, I thought that you tried to use the script of Javascript as Google Apps Script. You want to delete the label using Google Apps Script. If my understanding of what you want is correct, how about this sample script?

Javascript code at [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/delete) cannot be used on the script editor as Google Apps Script. If you want to delete the label using Google Apps Script, you can use the deleteLabel method of Class GmailLabel. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

This sample script is from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label#deleteLabel()).

```
function myFunction() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("MyLabel");
  label.deleteLabel();
}
```

#### Reference:

- [deleteLabel() of Class GmailLabel](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label#deleteLabel())

#### Note:

- If you want to use Javascript code in the script editor as Javascript, you can also use it using [the Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), [the custom dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs) and [custom sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars) of Google Docs.

If I misunderstand your situation, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: @masavini I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.